# Как очистить результаты фильтра переданные в $_POST?

Tags: php, html, form

Есть на странице сайта `wordpress` фильтр, который выводит данные в зависимости от возраста на той же странице.

Привожу полный код фильтра:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label class="ages">Введите возраст:
        <input type="number" name="age"/>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
<div>
<?php
$args = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'method', 
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'meta_query' => array(
       'key' => 'age_min',
       'value' => (int) $_POST["age"],
       'type'    => 'numeric',
       'compare' => '<='
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, кнопка при клике на кнопку `<button>Очистить результат</button>` происходил сброс результатов и возвращение на исходную позицию наподобие:

```
if (isset($_POST['age'])) {
  unset($_POST['age']));
}
```

**UPD:** решение есть, но оно неполное - нужно отправить такую же форму с пустым значением

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="age" value="">Очистить результат</button>
</form>
```

, но есть нюанс: `$_POST['age']` может иметь значение **0**, а `value=""` как раз к нему приравнивается и теперь фильтр срабатывает по нулю

Comment: с вашей репой грех такое спрашивать)) что где выводит? аякс, чистый хтмл/пхп?

Comment: @Jean-Claude чистый. ну туплю я где-то, не получается. Думал что-то типа того прокатит
`<input type="button" value="Очистить результат" onclick="getElementsByName('age')[0].value = ''">` ан нет..

Comment: @Вася, а чем <input type="reset"> не подходит?

Comment: document.querySelector('input[name="age"]').value = '';

Comment: @Nsk поясните. Вы имеете ввиду очистку перед отправкой формы? Но, мне нужно изменять уже значение `$_POST['age']` после отправки

Comment: @Виктор Пупкин прочитайте внимательно мой комментарий над вашим. Чем он отличается, что должен сработать?

Comment: UPD: привел полный код фильтра в вопросе

Comment: вообще работает и так и эдак, может у вас елемент с именем name присутствует несколько раз на странице? и он совсем не в [0] индексе

Comment: @Виктор Пупкин подождите. Прочитайте внимательно вопрос: я привел код полного фильтра. Мне нужно не на входе результат очищать, что вы предлагаете и я сам знаю несколько способов, а после отправки формы и получения `$_POST['age']`, т.е. в последнем обнулить результаты, что исходные получились

Comment: у вас что после отправки формы и загрузки результатов в инпут присутствует значение которое вы передавали?

Comment: @Виктор Пупкин да